# VBox and Docker: Building image (13: Permission denied)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtualbox

I would like to create and run a docker image inside my virtual box.

Here is simple Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mariadb-server

EXPOSE 3306/tcp

CMD ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"];
```

but when i try to build it inside virtual box using this command
`sudo docker build -t test .` I get this error

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-vendor-ubuntu - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-autoremove-suggests - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes - open (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages - open (13: Permission denied)
```

How do I give permission to read this files? There is probably a clash between user priviledges inside image that is being built and vbox, but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Did you run it as a sudo ?

Comment: Yes I am using sudo. I edited the question to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

How are you building the dockerfile? 
Try building it using sudo

```
sudo docker build -t $TAG -f $DOCKERFILE .
```

Comment: Yeah I am using that command. There is probably a clash between user priviledges inside image that is being built and vbox, but I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You should update **docker-compose**:

```
apt update && apt install docker-compose -y
```

The default version is too old.